# Firestore Rules: Error performing setData, PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following lines to write data to the users collections:

```
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
  await databaseReference.collection("users")
      .document(userData['uid'])
      .setData(userData);
```

and `userData` is: {uid: b4WRYgXae8QIq9e3jTHscMPjvtk1, phone: +17031110000}.

I have applied the following rules, which contains the line `allow write: if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid)`

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{docId} {
      allow read: if (true);
      allow write: if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid)
      allow read, write: if (request.auth.uid == 'xxxxx')
    }
    match /orders/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid)
      allow read, write: if (request.auth.uid == 'xxxxx')
    }
  }
}
```

But flutter I giving the following error:

```
  I/System.out(  931): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    I/System.out(  931): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    W/Firestore(  931): (21.4.2) [Firestore]: Write failed at users/b4WRYgXae8QIq9e3jTHscMPjvtk1: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
    E/flutter (  931): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing setData, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient
```

Answer (score 1):

In security rules, [`resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) refers to the *existing* data in a document.  If there is no existing document, then there is no value there, and any checks against its contents will fail, the rule will reject access.

Incoming document data is in [`request.resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource), so you might want to change your rule to be like this:

```
allow write: if (request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid);
```

This will require the client to always provide a uid field that matches their own Auth uid for documents in the users collection.